# Javascript enlarge image on click (without frameworks)

Tags: javascript, json, api, onclick

I am new to JS and here.
This code upload photos from JSON with a size limit on the photo. How to increase on click?

```
function renderUserPhotos(data, container) {
  var content = "";
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var title = data[i].title ? data[i].title : 'None';
    var url= data[i] ? data[i].url : null;
    var id = data[i].id;
    content += "<li class='photo'><img width='50px' src='" + url + "' /></li>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add eventListeners with pure JS to any element and manipulate the elements CSS in the event function.

So something like this should work:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.photo img');
elements.forEach((element) => {
 element.addEventListener('click', function() {
   element.style.width = '100px';
 });
});
```

Note, that this can only be called after the images are actually rendered. An alternative would be, to add the event listener directly within the creation:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var title = data[i].title ? data[i].title : 'None';
    var url= data[i] ? data[i].url : null;
    var id = data[i].id;

    // Create <li> element
    var content = document.createElement('li');
    content.classList.add('photo');

    // Create <img> element
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = url;
    img.style.width = '50px';

    // Register event listener
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
     element.style.width = '100px';
    })

    // Append the image to the list element
    content.appendChild(img);

    ...
}
```